# try ... catch not working

Tags: objective-c, exception

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) { <br>

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

int a1,b1,c1;
@try {      
    NSLog(@"Enter numerator: ");
    scanf("%i",&a1);
    NSLog(@"Enter denomenator: ");
    scanf("%i",&b1);
    c1 = a1/b1;
    NSLog(@"%i",c1);
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog([e name]);
    NSLog([e description]);
    NSLog([e reason]);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"inside finally block");
}
[pool drain]; 

return 0; 

}
```

Here if i enter value of a1=10, b1=0, then there should be exception generated, so statement within catch block will supposed to be execute. But it doesn't. Program crashed. Try..Catch doesn't work in this case ......Looks like i am doing something wrong...

Comment: It shows Program received signal:  “EXC_ARITHMETIC”, but catch statements doesn't execute at all.

Comment: Objective-C is not Java.  Not all signalled errors are exceptions.  In fact, exceptions are something of an, er, exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the floating point exception which is caused by C code (c1 = a1/b1).
This is not wrapped in a NSException.

If you want to go through the catch block, you can replace your FPE code with

```
[[NSString string] setValue:@"" forKeyPath:@"KP"];
```

which will trigger a NSUnknownKeyException.

Answer (score 3):

try/catch will only work for Obj-C exceptions that are thrown. They are quite high-level constructs. This is probably different from the Java try/catch blocks, that let you catch almost everything.

Comment: Not almost. Everything :) All exceptions are subclasses of Throwable. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html
IMO unless it is a low memory or high cpu related error, it can be caught.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the OP just wants an example of try-catch-finally.
Just in case anyone is else needs it, here's a basic example
to work with ARC:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        @try {
            @throw ([NSException exceptionWithName:@"MyException"
                                            reason:@"Just testing"
                                          userInfo:nil]);
        }
        @catch (NSException *ex) {
            NSLog(@"Exception caught: %@", ex);
        }
        @finally {
            NSLog(@"Finally is executed whether there's an exception or not");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```